# Regex remove punctuation but not between digits incorrect result

Tags: python, regex

I am preprocessing text for SpaCy and trying to remove punctuation, except for between digits. However, in some cases when punctuation is concatenated with digits it's not removed. Could you please suggest how to deal with this edge case?

An example:

```
import re

text = "Fast-charge $ EV ! battery maker StoreDot pulls in $80.7M led led by Vietnam’s VinFast"

preprocessed = re.sub(r'(?<!\d)[%$!.,,;:’“”—-](?!\d)',' ', text)

print(preprocessed)

# Fast charge   EV   battery maker StoreDot pulls in $80.7M led by Vietnam s VinFast
```

Expected result:

```
# Fast charge   EV   battery maker StoreDot pulls in 80.7M led by Vietnam s VinFast
```

Comment: Perhaps assert not a digit on one side? `(?<!\d)[$!.,;:’“”—-]|[$!.,;:’“”—-](?!\d)` https://regex101.com/r/JD2oEK/1

Comment: What do you specifically want to keep as is? Only digits with comma's and dots in between?

Comment: @JvdV yes, I want to leave numbers only so SpaCY could recognize it as a number. Essentially I struggle with $ and %.

Comment: @Thefourthbird not sure why, but this doesn't work with cases like "bitcoin is off 4.3% and ether 5.1%, according to Coinbase data"

Comment: @Cassiopea But it does give the expected result here? https://regex101.com/r/jXrccs/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird, awesome, thank you so much, yes it works! Could you please maybe explain it in an answer, would really appreciate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The negative lookarounds should be true at both sides, so that will not match the `$` in `$80`

You can match one character of the character class asserting that either on the left or on the right side using an alternation `|` that there is no digit.

```
(?<!\d)[%$!.,;:’“”—-]|[%$!.,;:’“”—-](?!\d)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jXrccs/1)

**Notes**

- There is `led led` in the example string, and a single `led` in the expected result, but I assume that is a typo, because the character class can not match `led`
- There is also a double entry for the `,` in the character class.
- Not sure if you want to keep them, but using a space in the replacement can leave double spaced gaps as you can see in the expected result. If you want to remove them, you can use `strip()` to remove the leading and trailing spaces, and use sub with `r"[^\S\n]{2,}"` to match 2 or more spaces without newline chars and replace them with a single space

Comment: thank you so much for an amazing explanation, it is much clearer now. Especially thank you for the double spaces comment, I indeed have this issue!

Comment: @Cassiopea You are most welcome :-) Good luck!